# Android: cannot insert data in MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, crash

I am trying this example from website. in which I am inserting data in MYSQL. the problem i m facing is that when i enter my data and press ok button my application after few seconds crashes and no data is inserted in database. I am using emulator. here are my codes.

```
public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText user, pass;
private Button mRegister;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/allevents/username.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");


            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);


            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());


            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";


public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {


    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}


public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


    try {


        if (method == "POST") {


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}
```

My PHP file is

```
<?php
$response = array();


if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];




// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(Username,Password) VALUES('$username', '$password')");
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Operation successfull";
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of my logcat
http://i57.tinypic.com/4exk8.png

Comment: Look in you LogCat and in your server logfile to find out what is happend.

Comment: "my application after few seconds crashes" Define "crash". what's your logcat showing?

Comment: crash -> application has stopped working

Comment: :) I was asking about error logs. Copy message from your Logcat.

Comment: i tried copying my logcat but when i save logcat it gives me empty file here is screenshot of logcat http://i57.tinypic.com/4exk8.png

Comment: Null pointer exception in your doInBackground(). What's in your line 110?

Comment: Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this snipped of code from **doInBackground** method and put it in onPostExecute().

```
    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());


                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the editTexts user & pass in your AsyncTask doInBackground().
Give them to it as params of .execute() in your Activity
(NOTE: in your OnClickListener you have to get them from Scratch!):

```
String[]  myparams = 
{
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString(),
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString()
};
new CreateUser().execute(myparams);
```

Now you can extract them in your AsyncTask:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... pParams)
{
    String username = pParams[0];
    String password= pParams[1];

    //Do what you like.
}
```

I think that is the reason for the NullPointerException in your log-screenshot. ;)

Hope this helps...